# ¿Cómo saber si una consulta no devuelve nada?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql

[image: Tengo esto.]

Si encuentra los datos ya me los muestra pero cómo le haría para saber si la consulta no me devuelve nada?, es decir que no existe lo que se busca.

Comment: Pon el código mejor que una imagen.

Comment: Como dice @blonfu, es recomendable poner el codigo porque la imagen puede romperse y tu pregunta quedar inservible. ademas que con el codigo en texto podemos copiar y pegar para probar en nuestros entornos. Un saludo

Comment: Suponiendo que usas [pg-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise), deberias usar el método llamado [one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise#query-result-mask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice la [documentación](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-result-mask) :

```
db.any(query, values); // expects anything, same as `manyOrNone`
db.manyOrNone(query, values); // expects anything, same as `any`
```

- many|none - data is an array of objects. When no rows are returned, data is an empty array.

Entonces se puede entender que cuando el query no encuentra resultados devuelve un arreglo vació, el cual fácilmente puedes comprobar con un simple

```
if (data.length) {
    // hay datos encontrados
} else {
   // lo que tengas que hacer cuando no los hay
}
```

Para más información consulta el [código fuente](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/5ed380e2e1a34877be5d72038a832428710004d5/lib/database.js#L558)

Answer (score 0):

simplemente declara una variable con la siguiente consulta:

```
'select count(*) from tienda.usuariocliente where nombre_usuario= $1', pupID
```

eso te arroja un dato entero, lo cual puedes poner en una condición si es 0 o mayor.